# Keeping mulch from washing off of banks and steep inclines

Tags: landscaping, mulch

I have mulched multiple hills and am always looking for ways to keep mulch 'glued' to hillsides. Switching to decorative shale is unfortunately not an option.

I have tried three things:

- Ground covers (Junipers etc.)
- Chicken wire (Looks horrible once it does wash away)
- Single shredded bark seems to stay put longer than fine & double shredded.

I have heard of a clear glue spray, not sure what it is called though.

Does anyone on here know of ways to keep mulch on hill sides longer?

I can post a picture of the bank(s), but we do more than one bank mulching so it's general to almost any incline.

Comment: Are plantings on these banks an option for you? You mentioned "Junipers etc" but didn't say what the outcome was there, or if you'd consider similar options.

Comment: Plants (like Junipers) hold it in place in the area of the plant, but most of it still washes away.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, it tends to want to wash down the hill.  A real pain.

I have had better luck with cypress mulch staying in place over the pine bark stuff.

Wondering if some black netting pinned down in several horizontal pieces would hold things back.  Put some mulch down, black net and then cover with a layer of mulch.  Just an idea.

Seems like plants are the best option if terracing is out.  They tend to provide anchors on the hill.

Comment: I like that net idea - similar to chicken wire but not as ugly? I'll have to give that a try.